# Is there any way to create a react native project with - (dash) in project name?

Tags: android, react-native, rename

I am trying to create a react native project named **'work-mobile'**. *(- in project name)*
When I do `npx react-native init work-mobile` the cli give me error ***"work-mobile" is not a valid name for a project. Please use a valid identifier name (alphanumeric).***.

I have tried first creating the project with **_** (underscore) in name like **'work_mobile'** and then using **react-native-rename** to rename the project but it also gives the same error like react-native-cli error.

I have tried manually doing that.

- Renamed the folder name.
- Renamed in package.json and app.json
- Deleted iOS and android folders
- Recreated using react native eject.

The iOS app starts working but for android now it doesn't connect to metro bundler. A blank screen appears on emulator. When I reload from metro, it say No apps connected I have tried starting bundler manually, reinstalling node mules, clearing cache, gradle cleaning etc things. [image] Any experience with that kind of thing?

Answer (score -1):

If you used "WorkMobile" as the name, react would automatically change that to work-mobile when it creates the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just did that in react native and it named it exactly how I specified. No changes to a name with dashes occured.